# Replace dropped item with jquery-sortable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using this plugin (https://github.com/johnny/jquery-sortable) to drag and drop row between two tables.

Is there a way to replace dropped item to dragged one? Also I need to allow specific rows to be dropped, is it possible?

```
$("#table-compras").sortable({
        group: 'no-drop',
        containerSelector: "table",
        itemPath: "> tbody",
        itemSelector: "tr",
        drag: false
    });
    $("#table-vendas-nao-associadas").sortable({
        group: 'no-drop',
        containerSelector: "table",
        itemPath: "> tbody",
        itemSelector: "tr"
    });
```

In the example below I have 2 tables. "COMPRAS" is only droppable and "VENDAS NÃO ASSOCIADAS" is only draggable. The line in pink is supposed to be the only slot available to be dropped. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Show us the html, but the solution is probably $("table.emptyrow").droppable ,something like that

Comment: @MrJack you mean the HTML for the tables?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery's sortable widget and the configuration of connected lists and excluding items: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#items